# Syntax related query during variable declaration and initialization

Tags: c, initialization

Consider the following code snippet

```
int main(){
 int a, b, c;
 printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
 return 0;
}
```

This is going to display some garbage value.
Now, consider this snippet.

```
int main(){
 int a, b, c = 0;
 printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
 return 0;
}
```

This displays `0 0 0` for every execution. But I've only initialized variable `c` to `0`. Is this some shorthand for doing something like, `int a=0, b=0, c=0;`

Don't know how to look for such doubt in official documentation.

Comment: The values of `a` and `b` are indeterminate in both versions. It's just by accident that they're being set to `0` in the second one. The compiler might be using an optimization when initializing `c` that happens to fill the whole block of memory with zeroes.

Comment: Just because the values are indeterminate it doesn't mean they have to be garbage. They can be anything, including zero..

Comment: @Barmar, that means even though `a`, `b` are being initialized to `0`, that is still garbage value?

Comment: They have to contain something. 0 is just as good as anything else.

Comment: To understand what's happening, you should really look at the assembly code. To request the assembly code from gcc, use the `-S` option. Or better yet, step through the assembly with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without initialization, `a, b` are *indeterminate* right after `int a, b, c = 0;`

Their values are neither certainly consistent (they could be [random](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)) nor safe to access.

> If an initialization is specified for the object, ...; otherwise, the value
> becomes **indeterminate** each time the declaration is reached.   C17dr §6.2.4 6

> **indeterminate value**
> either an **unspecified value** or a **trap representation** 3.19.2

> **unspecified value**
> valid value of the relevant type where this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance 3.19.3

> **trap representation**
> an object representation that need not represent a value of the object type 3.19.4

---

> Didn't know how to look for such doubt in official documentation.

See [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/2410359) and search the spec for *initialization*.

Comment: Thank you very much! Found it very insightful and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a` and `b` are getting garbage on both examples. The only difference is that their garbage are different on each execution.
Like, they are put on an address that can contain anything, as, -2130381 or 83943097 or even **0**. X% of the times you can get a 0 on an uninitialized value, and it will work on the first Y modifications of the code. After that, your code can just broke and you may spend some time debugging it.